# Musical note symbols on Android

Tags: android, symbols

I'm working on an a piano quiz app and I'm at the point where I need to write all the letter notes on the keyboard, more exactly when the user tries to guess what note was played and will press a key the musical letter will appear on that key.

This a screenshot of the app when the user touches a key:
[image]

My question is related to the musical symbol flat:

[image]

How can I achieve that symbol and implement it in the app? For example dflat is shown as "DB" and I need to rewrite it to "Dflat", flat as the musical symbol.

Edit: The letter notes are shown as text views.

Comment: Do you want a text or image of the flat symbol?

Comment: The flat symbol as text!

Comment: Something like: sampleText.setText("Dflat");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking whether there is a text character for a flat symbol? If so, check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Are you asking how to set the font to one that supports said character? If so, check out the setTypeface() method of TextView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

You might also consider using icons instead of text.

Edit: The unicode character for the flat symbol ♭ is 266D, and you can use unicode in Java via the \u escape character. Something like this:

```
sampleText.setText("\u266D");
```

You have to be using a font that supports that character. And more importantly, so do your users. That's why it might be a better idea to use an icon instead.